# Spark withColumn doesn't add a new column to dataframe, updated

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add a new column to a spark dataframe.
I also want to keep a variable to the column .
For that I am using the following broken line of code:

```
val workProjection: Column = df.withColumn("working",df.select(workColumns: _*).columns.map(c => col(c)/60).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))("working")
```

Alternatively, the following line does the trick:

```
val workProjection: Column =when(df("telfs") < 3, "working").otherwise("not working").as("working")
```

Why does the second line gives the requested result while the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is when I check the content of df after executing this line of code, there is no columns

And it shouldn't. As all operations in Spark `withColumn` creates a new `DataFrame`. Instead checking `df` you should check `workProjection`

Comment: I updated my question. Can you update your answer please?